# Is it possible to add a gif to a still image?

Tags: photo-editing, gif

I really want to add a gif to a still image but I have no idea if it's possible. Thanks for anyone's help ♥

Comment: A motion gif in a static "image"?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. Do you think you can provide some more info as well as the software you are hoping to work with?

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a still image in an animated gif? If so, the answer is [yes, absolutely!](https://imgur.com/FQazESq). Just make sure the still image appears in each frame of the animation

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add more details? It would make it easier to give you a good answer.

Comment: I believe they're asking for something like "hey I have a gif of a mouth and a png of a character, how do I put the mouth on the character?"

Answer (score 3):

No. You can not "add" a gif to a still image.

You **can** create a gif where only a *portion* of the image is animated.  However the format *must* be gif if there is animation within the image. Gifs do *not* have to animate everything in every frame.

These are gif images where only a small portion of the image is actually animated. These are often called **Cinemagraphs**:

> [image] 
>   [image]
>   [image]
> [[source]](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/cinemagraph/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want an image file to be animated, it will have to be in a .GIF format. However, there are tricks you can do to make it seem like a part of the image is moving while the other parts remain still. So let's say you have 10 frames of the animation. The part you want still - let's say it's the right side of the image. All 10 frames of the right side should look the same. Now, if you want something on the left moving, all 10 frames of the left side of the image should look animated. So it will look like part of the image is moving, but the whole file would be a .GIF format. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not perfectly clear for me but:
Gif images has their own format, .gif format, that represent animated images.
Other static format for example .jpeg/.png/.svg couldn't be gif (intended as animated images).
You can make instead a gif inside a still image in 2 methods (those are indeed the same method):

-Make a .gif image with a part static and a part animated

-Make a video project, with a static image as background (or where you want your static 
 img to be) and a video/.gif.
 Then you can convert your video in a .gif image.
You can do this with software like adobe after effect, sony vegas etc..